# Finding the distribution of $Y$, the minimum of some IID random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

As I'm learning multivariate distributions and some special distributions such as gamma, chi-sqaure, I'm having a hard time understanding the concepts between the two questions i'm about to write. Following questions are from a textbook from hogg

> $Q_1$ : Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ be four independent random variables, each with pdf 
>   $$f(x) =\begin{cases}
> 3(1-x)^2, & 0 < x < 1,\\
> 0,& \text{elsewhere}.
> \end{cases}$$
>   If $Y$ is the minimum of these four variables, find the cdf and the pdf of $Y$.
>   Hint: $P(Y>y) = P(X_i > y, i=1,\dotsc,4)$.
>
> $Q_2$ : Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be iid random variables, each with pdf 
>   $$f(x) =\begin{cases}
> e^{-x},& 0 < x < \infty,\\
> 0, & \text{elsewhere}.
> \end{cases}.$$
>   Find the distribution of $Y = \min(X_1,X_2,X_3)$.
>   Hint: $P(Y \le y) = 1 - P(Y>y) = 1 - P(X_i > y, i=1,2,3)$

From these two questions above, I don't quite understand how both question is asking for the minimum, yet their hints are totally opposite. Could someone explain this?

Comment: The hints are essentially the same. Taking the first hint, and subtracting both sides from $1$ gives you the second hint (or vice versa). Note that $P(Y \le y)$ is the cdf.

Comment: @angryavian oh so can you apply the first hint to the second question and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In either case, you are asked to find the cdf. Generally, you have the option to find the pdf first or the cdf. Here, you are being guided into finding the cdf first because it happens to be easier.

Now, to find the cdf would be to calculate $P(Y\leq y)$. In words, this means that the minimum $Y$ has to smaller than some constant $y$. But this is a hard approach because you're placing an "upperbound" (for lack if a better word) on the minimum. Instead, it is easier to consider a "lowerbound" on the minimum, $Y>y$. To get this, we notice that
$$P(Y\leq y) = 1- P(Y>y).$$

In words, this means that the minimum has to be larger than $y$. This means that each $X_k$ has to be greater than $y$,
$$P(Y\leq y) = 1- P(Y>y) = 1-P\left(\bigcap_{k = 1}^n X_k >y\right) = 1-\prod_{k=1}^nP(X_k>y)$$
where the last equality is true by independence. Since the $X_k$ are iid, we have
$$1-\prod_{k=1}^nP(X_k>y) = 1 - [P(X_1>y)]^n.$$

Comment: Thank you Max. I got confused because hint seemed opposite when they both are asking minimum. Are you saying that I can use $P(Y \le y) = 1- P(Y > y)$ for both question and obtain same answer?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the second one also asked for the pdf. But yes, the key part is that in both problems, you are asked to find $P(Y\leq y)$, and I have provided the general idea. Notice that in each case, you use $P(Y>y)$, except in the first problem, it was not entirely clear where the idea came from or how to use it.